# Seasonal and trend adjustment for irregularly spaced time series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, seasonality, trend, data-preprocessing

I know of different methods that exist to remove seasonality and trend in the data to make it stationary. However, that exists only for regular time series; that is, a series that follows a fixed frequency. For example, a series that has a daily recording of temperature. But what about methods for irregular time series where data is ordered by time, but doesn't follow a fixed time pattern, that is, it is not regularly spaced, data comes suddenly, sales data, when some days don't sell?

What methods are there to stationarize irregular time series if they are non-stationary (seasonal and trendy)?

timestamp I have:

```
timestamp    p1    p2   p3
2014/03/01    5    6    4
2014/03/02    6    6    8
2014/03/03    9    25   20
2014/03/05    9    5    55
2014/03/08    0    2    4
```

Comment: It sounds like your time series is regularly spaced (i.e. one measurement per day) but sometimes the measurement is missing for some reason. Is this the case?

Comment: @jcken or perhaps there are no missing observations but the seasonal cycle varies in length such as ordinary vs. leap year.

Comment: @RichardHardy good point; OP is there is a specific problem you're interested in? Elaborating can help us to find the best tool for the job

Comment: No, not regularly spaced, but rather data comes suddenly, sales data. For example: Look at the updated answer

Comment: You can have irregular spacing in calendar time that does not cause irregular statistical patterns. Imagine a sequence generated by an ARIMA(p,d,q) and indexed by $t=1,\dots,T$. Now replace the indices with some random (but monotonically increasing) time labels. You can still model the series as ARIMA(p,d,q) and just ignore the time labels. This is often done with e.g. daily stock returns. People tend to ignore the calendar time of such series without much loss of information. I am not saying you should do the same, but you should think about it and about what you mean by not regularly spaced.

Comment: To remove the ambiguity, I updated it again. For seasonality, they use actually SARIMA model, but I don't know yet if this is a method along with ARIMA.